# Select local files with input type:file (pdf) and convert them to base64 string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, base64

how to get base64 string from selected files with input type: file (multiple .pdf) in javascript.
I need a base64 string in a variable.

```
 function handleFileSelect(e) {
            console.dir(e);
            if (!e.target.files) return;
            selDiv.innerHTML = "";
            var files = e.target.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                var base64;
                var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("files").files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
                    base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                    console.log(base64);
                };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);

                var f = files[i];
                var TmpPath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]);
                var name = f.name;
                var extencion = f.name.split('.')[1];

                selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='#' onclick=verdetalle(" + i + ",'" + extencion + "','" + name + "','" + base64 + "','" + TmpPath + "')>Ver Detalle</a>" + "<br/>";
            }
        }
```

but I do not respect the value for my base64 variable, only if I debuge it from the browser.

in this line of my code I create a link for each selected file, where I assign an onchange and pass the variables i, extension, name, base64, TmpPath, but I am missing the base64 variable

```
selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='#' onclick=verdetalle(" + i + ",'" + extencion + "','" + name + "','" + base64 + "','" + TmpPath + "')>Ver Detalle</a>" + "<br/>";
```

Comment: code please....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code snippet,

```js
var base64String;
function handleFileSelect(callback) {    
    var file = document.getElementById('filePicker').files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            base64String = btoa(binaryString);
            // alert(base64String);
            // Do additional stuff
            callback(base64String);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
};
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <label for="filePicker">Choose file:</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="filePicker" onchange="handleFileSelect(function(base64String){alert(base64String)})">
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: but how do I assign the base64 string to a variable?

Comment: var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
                    base64String = btoa(binaryString);
                    alert(base64String);

Comment: var binaryString can not be used outside of its function?  programtreasures?

Comment: @Bichito you need to do further stuff in in reader onload function after generating base 64 string, you will not get any variable value from outside of the function

Comment: @Bichito no you cant return it but you can create a callback function from it

Comment: Can I do a return of the variable base64String, to retrieve the string string or how could this variable get out of the function, to pass it as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the functionality that depends on `base64` inside the `filereader.onload` callback. Also, make sure to always use `const` or `let` when dealing with asynchronous loops. `var` gets hoisted and has function scope, not block scope, so it's easy to run into problems if you use it. Or, even better, use `forEach`, which gives you better abstraction, doesn't require manual iteration, and has function scope:

```
function handleFileSelect(e) {
  console.dir(e);
  const files = e.target.files;
  if (!files) return;
  selDiv.innerHTML = "";
  files.forEach((file, i) => {
    const { name } = file;
    const extencion = f.name.split('.')[1];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      const base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      console.log(base64);
      const TmpPath = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='#' onclick=verdetalle(" + i + ",'" + extencion + "','" + name + "','" + base64 + "','" + TmpPath + "')>Ver Detalle</a>" + "<br/>";
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```